# Django redis cache rebuild

Tags: python, django, redis

We have an application for which the daily data needs to be updated in the cache. So if we flush out the data is there any easy way of rebuilding the cache without visiting all the pages and combinations. Is there any way to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

I create a **decorator class** for **temporal caching** data from "sql-lite" with Django model:
Does this method any help you?

## Decorator:

```
class MWT(object):
    """Memoize With Timeout CACHE as a decorator"""
    _caches = {}
    _timeouts = {}

    def __init__(self, timeout=2):
        self.timeout = timeout

    def collect(self):
        """Clear cache of results which have timed out"""
        for func in self._caches:
            cache = {}
            for key in self._caches[func]:
                if (time.time() - self._caches[func][key][1]) < self._timeouts[func]:
                    cache[key] = self._caches[func][key]
            self._caches[func] = cache

    def __call__(self, f):
        self.cache = self._caches[f] = {}
        self._timeouts[f] = self.timeout

        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            kw = kwargs.items()
            kw.sort()
            key = (args, tuple(kw))
            try:
                v = self.cache[key]
                if (time.time() - v[1]) > self.timeout:
                    raise KeyError
            except KeyError:
                v = self.cache[key] = f(*args, **kwargs), time.time()
            return v[0]

        func.func_name = f.func_name

        return func
```

## My model:

```
class MySimpleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.name, self.id)

    def __set__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

Then I use this method **(defined decorator)** to reading the Django model:

```
class SQLData(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def name(self):
        return self._name


@MWT(timeout=10)  # You can set any value to timeout (time of clearing cache).
def sql_reader():
    return list(MySimpleModel.objects.all())  # Using list method as faster to read sql.

class GetData(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get_data(cls):
        result = []

        for data in sql_reader():
            data = SQLData(data.name)
            result.append(data)

        return result
```

---